# Approachs to load thousands of records into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, doctrine

I have been developing a php application in symfony1 that loads thousands of records from a excel file and evaluates them in the script, and finally inserts them in the MySQL database. I saw that the script is taking to much to load. Im using doctrine 1 to insert the data with transactions.

My questions are:

should I use an ORM or should I use raw SQL for inserting task? is there any performance related between them?

Should I convert the excel file in a CSV, to consume less memory?

Should I use anything else to load the files like other scripting language specifically for this task? files sizes are between 10MB and 50MB

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this is an option but i usually use excel to write out all my insert statements into a field in the excel sheet. then i copy the formula down the page copying all the inserts. then i just copy paste them into mysql workbench and execute them. once you have the formula you can just copy it to other excel sheets. its pretty fast. maybe not an option though

Comment: The problem is that Im thinking in an automated solution in the application just for a user tu upload the file and wait for confirm, so your solution wouldnt work for me right know.

Comment: phpmyadmin has an import from excel feature. maybe you can hack the code and see how they did it

Answer (score 1):

Mauro, you can still create a friendly interface in your application to import the records into your database. However using raw sql is definitely the best way to do so. Through PHP you can manipulate your system's resources. Once you've got the file's path (I'd recommend to use CSV) you can issue any command in your system such as:

```
<?php
shell_exec("mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -e 'YOUR SCRIPT TO IMPORT THE DATA HERE'");
...
OR
<?php
shell_exec("mysqlimport -uUSER -pPASSWORD 'YOUR CRITERIA HERE'");
...
```

I believe it is the best approach for that. Let us know how you sort it out!

Comment: Thanks! I totally was in making it with ORM and PHP functions how fool of me! I changed it to raw sql and converted the excel into a csv and it loaded a 30MB file fairly more quickly than before! :D